# How to equate ['1'] with 1 in flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 variables

```
a=['1'] # This is an array
b=1 # This is a integer
```

I want (a==b) to be true.

Answer (score 0):

In your array `a=['1']` is a `String` not an `integer` so it won't become equal

```
a = [1]
b = 1
for i in a:
    if i == b:
        print('a==b')
    else:
        print('a!=b')
```